# Verificar se campo está vazio, usando função de leitura customizada em C

Tags: c, string

```
void vazio(void)
{
    char *str = NULL, c;//apontando para null
    int i = 0, j = 1;

    //alocação de memória para str
    str = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char));
    printf("Informe a string: ");
    //ler a string
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        c = getc(stdin);//ler a entrada padrão do teclado
        str = (char *) realloc (str, j*sizeof(char));//realocação de     memória 
        str[i] = c;//ler o caracter, fazendo apontar para c
        ++i;
        ++j;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';//marcar final da string com caracter nulo

    //gets(str);//usando gets, o escopo if é executado
    if((strlen(str) == 0) || (strcmp(str,"0") == 0))
    {
        printf("\7\aErro!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //isto é executado, mas não imprime nada, ignorando o if acima
        printf("String: %s", str);

    free(str);//libera memória
    str = NULL;//evita o dangling pointers
}
```

Comment: Fazer com que erro seja emitido, pois com gets() funciona.

Comment: Caso o usuário deixe o campo em branco, ou seja dê enter, o programa vai emitir um beep, imprimindo erro e consequentemente fechará usando o exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que fazer algumas alterações para compilar. O código sequer compilava no meu compilador com as configurações que eu uso. Coloquei um `if` dentro do `while` porque a realocação e adição do caractere à *string* só deve ser feita se o caractere não é o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Este caractere deve ser desprezado sempre. Quando se digita alguma coisa até funciona mesmo que a intenção seja diferente. Mas quando não se digita nada ele cria um problema porque a *string* tem tamanho 1 que é ocupado pelo `\n`.

Dá para escrever este código de uma forma melhor mas não quis descaracterizar mais seu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//tirei os comentários porque eles davam indicações erradas mesmo
//o erro de runtime é provocado propositalmente pelo código através da função exit
void vazio(void) {
    char *str = malloc(1);
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Informe a string: ");
    do {
        c = getc(stdin);
        if (c != '\n') {
            str = realloc(str, i + 1);
            str[i++] = c;
        }
    } while (c != '\n');
    str[i] = '\0';
    if(strlen(str) == 0 || strcmp(str, "0") == 0) {
        printf("\7\a\nErro!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nString: %s", str);
    free(str);
}

int main(void) {
    vazio();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/c4uWUj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ValidationEmpty). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ValidationEmpty.c).

Você está usando técnicas antigas e desnecessárias de programar em C.

Comment: funfou legal. Valeu

Comment: Em qual parte do código há técnicas antigas e desnecessárias?

Comment: O uso do malloc não precisa fazer *cast*, o tamanho do char foi padronizado como 1 em todos os compiladores e plataformas, você tentou usar `gets`. Além disto tem algumas coisas que deixa o código menos legível ou fazendo coisas que não precisam. Um exemplo é atribuir `NULL` para o ponteiro para evitar pendência de ponteiro. Veja o código do [ideone](http://ideone.com/x3otLA) como ficou mais limpo.

Comment: valeu amigo, até